# Custom filter on dspace 7.5

Tags: dspace

in DSpace 7.5, i have a dataset with the following properties:
[image: item coordinates]

These property appears and are indexed on solr

[image]

I've also added the proper bean in discovery.xml to allow search based on the previous property
[image: DiscoverySearchFilterFaced for east coordinate]

And I'm able to see the filter for the property i needed

[image: east coordinate facet filter]

but this filter only search for exactly value while i need a filter that allow to filter by range (for example from 11.000 to 12.000 and match 11.433)

How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance